# Why are there different ways to describe same design pattern using UML? What to trust?

Tags: design-patterns, iterator, uml, software-design, class-diagram

I find it difficult to learn both Design Pattern and UML since there are different ways to describe the same pattern which make me unsure what is the single source of truth.

Take **Iterator pattern** for example, here are just a few diagrams that I saw from well-known sites:

**1 WIKIPEDIA**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern

[image]

**2 TUTORIALS POINT**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/iterator_pattern.htm

[image]

**3 REFACTORING GURU**

https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/iterator

[image]

**4 OODESIGN**

https://www.oodesign.com/iterator-pattern.html

[image]

**5 HOWTODOINJAVA**

https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/behavioral/iterator-design-pattern/

[image]

What confuses me the most is how arrow symbols are used to describe the relationship between these classes. Sometimes they are generalization, sometimes interface realization, directed association or dependency. Even composition is also used...

I wonder what would be the best way for me to get my head around all this.

Comment: Buy the Design Patterns by Gamma et al. They "invented" it and should be right about the notation (TM). It's the first source mentioned in the Wiki literature.

Comment: That tutorialspoint is plain wrong. They use named associations instead of realizaion/generalization. That's a completely different thing. Not sure about which of the latter is used by Gamma; they have different meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, one needs to be very careful when looking at UML models for design patterns.  There are three reasons:

- The reference for design patterns is the [GoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns). This book was published in 1995, before UML even existed, and used a variation of the OMT notation (an ancestor of UML). In case if doubts, this is the source to trust.
- The Java language design was made public in 1995, JDK 1.0 release in January 1996, and the language not yet widely known.  The authors based their designs and code examples on a C++ class model, i.e. on classes and inheritance only, without bothering for multiple inheritance. Most modern languages do not support multiple inheritance.  As a consequence, some of the original patterns have to be adapted for Java, C# or Swift, to make a distinction between classes, abstract classes and interfaces, and between inheritance and interface implementation.  There are multiple ways to do this.  For example, some systematically converted abstract classes to interfaces.  Some converted them only when there was a conflict.  And some converted according to the interface "spirit".
- Misunderstandings happen.  Some people publish such diagrams on the net but misunderstand the pattern, or misunderstand UML, or both together.  Also, Gamma et al started the book when they were PhD students and also made some mistakes.  You'll find for example some inconcsitencies in their use of the OMT aggregation.
- The worst case is the Builder pattern, where you have not only those problems,  but on top of that you have a naming conflict: a very popular Java book introduced a (very different) variant of the builder pattern, with a different intent and another design, which caused total confusion.

Now to your specific example, and based on the content you have provided:

- **oodesign** is the closest to the original pattern and fully accurate. Btw, I mostly use links to their pages when it comes to patterns.
- **refactoring guru** is also a good choice.  They opted to use interfaces instead of abstract classes, which is fine. But they have redefined the interface's operations and properties (probably in relation to own examples) and require a bidirectional navigation that seems not justified.  If you're interested, there is a "[Head First: Design patterns](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-design/0596007124/)" which uses a similar mapping but keeps the original interface.
- **wikipedia** is not bad either: they have left out the client (which the GoF showed in light gray, to suggest that it's not essential for this pattern); They are more precise and complete on dependencies;  But they also redefined the operations and properties differently.  And they added an unnecessary aggregation symbol.
- **How to make it in Java** is confusing, because they kept one abstract class and opted for an interface for the other.  And they have hidden the operations and properties.  But there's nothing fundamentally wrong at first sight.
- Forget about **tutorial points**, at least for this UML diagram.  It's plain wrong, as [@qwerty_so](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3379653/qwerty-so) already mentioned in the comments.

The statement of accuracy is for this pattern only and for the current version of the content.  This cannot be generalized to all the design patterns in view of my introductory remarks.

Comment: The GoF book was originally published in October [1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) and Java was not made public (i.e. out of beta) until January [1996](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)#Versions). The timing of Java's release isn't necessarily germane to the question, since it isn't tagged as such. It only emphasizes the point that the material in the book is significantly older than most "modern" languages.

Comment: It's also important to mention that just because a website happens to be more accurate (today) with respect to the Iterator pattern, that does not mean the same website will be accurate with respect to another pattern. In my experience, Wikipedia has been very poor with the accuracy of design pattern articles (and also tends to change over time). Even after 25+ years, the book itself is still the most accurate representation of what its authors intended. All of these websites _will_ have some inconsistencies, so memorizing the patterns is not sufficient. Understanding their intent is critical.

Comment: @jaco0646 thank you for this precision (and for your edits by the way). The copyright notice in my own copy states 1995. Isn’t this the assumed date of publication? I read wikipedia but found no source to confirm the earlier claim. For Java I used 1995. More precisely May 1995 according to wikipedia source, or October 1995 according to the date of Goslings foundational public white paper that presents the language and the rationale of its design. See also [here](http://content.time.com/time/subscriber/article/0,33009,983903,00.html) . But important here is just that it’s after GOF publication

Comment: @jaco0646 I fully agree with the accuracy of web sites. Wikipedia is generally poor. And oodesign relatively good although not perfect. And indeed, the best resource is still the GoF, which also addresses some open questions with pros/cons whereas websites very often take position on those questions, this presenting a partial view of the original content. Long live GoF ! (if only s.o. could update the outdated examples) ;-)

Comment: @jaco0646 I’ve reworded the Java emergence and added the disclaimer regarding other patterns.

Comment: Well, that made me a good history lesson :-) I wonder why there is no UML update on the GoF book, or is there one?

Comment: @qwerty_so sometimes putting thing in the context really helps ;-) In fact, if they’d update and go for UML, they’d probably also have to replace some obsolete examples, and address the MI vs interface issue. Moreover they apparently [thought about an update in 2005](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1404056) but didn’t agree on dropping or regrouping differently some patterns (source found on wikipedia). Maybe a market opportunity?

Comment: It's now almost another 15 years. I wouldn't expect any update then. Probably the lot of "Design patterns for ..." books would make a market for "Design patterns for books on design patterns"?